# Heroku scheduler - schedule on demand (http post?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, sidekiq

We want to schedule/trigger jobs over HTTP.

Currently, we are using Heroku scheduler (because it doesn't need extra dyno/free) to schedule jobs. We need an ability to schedule them via HTTP POST or some other mechanism that we can trigger programmatically.

Any suggestions on how we can achieve this?